# SlowCheetah transform not working on jenkins build server - vs2010 - different drives

Tags: transform, slowcheetah

I have added slow Cheetah to 2 Solutions that I'm working with. The first one transforms when I'm working with it but not on the build server. The second one doesn't transform when I build it or on the build server.

Overall I'm a little confused when it comes to how to get slow cheetah working. I've read several links from Sayed and am struggling with which one I should be following. I have added version 2.5.5 to both projects.

1. http://sedodream.com/2012/12/24/SlowCheetahBuildServerSupportUpdated.aspx - This one says that I need to build a packagerestore.proj file first to restore the nuget package. However I get pathing errors when I try this ... I get this error - error MSB4019: The imported project "E:\jenkins\CAREweb.net (DEV APP BUILD)\workspace\development\systems\CARE\apps.nuget\nuget.targets" was not found.
2. http://sedodream.com/2011/12/12/SlowCheetahXMLTransformsFromACIServer.aspx - This is the one I would like to follow because I can just put the files on the ci server in the localappdata folder for the user that the jenkins service is running under. Solve it once for everyone on the team and for every build but it just doesn't transform and I don't seem to get any kind of error. Not sure if it makes a difference but we are building on the E: drive and the localappdata folder is on the c: drive.

I've read a number of his other posts on Slow Cheetah and I've looked at a bunch of the answers from stackoverflow but haven't found one that solves my problem yet.

We are using visual studio 2010. Building the project file on Jenkins from the command line. I'm sure that if I can get the one solution working then I should be able to get the other one working but I'm just not making any progress at the moment.

## Update

Also these are the related slow cheetah sections from my project file.

```
<PropertyGroup Label="SlowCheetah">
    <SlowCheetah_EnableImportFromNuGet Condition=" '$(SC_EnableImportFromNuGet)'=='' ">true</SlowCheetah_EnableImportFromNuGet>
    <SlowCheetah_NuGetImportPath Condition=" '$(SlowCheetah_NuGetImportPath)'=='' ">$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath( $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\packages\SlowCheetah.2.5.5\tools\SlowCheetah.Transforms.targets ))     </SlowCheetah_NuGetImportPath>
    <SlowCheetahTargets Condition=" '$(SlowCheetah_EnableImportFromNuGet)'=='true' and Exists('$(SlowCheetah_NuGetImportPath)') ">$(SlowCheetah_NuGetImportPath)</SlowCheetahTargets>
</PropertyGroup>

<Import Project="$(SlowCheetahTargets)" Condition="Exists('$(SlowCheetahTargets)')" Label="SlowCheetah" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with version 2.5.10. Ive modified SlowCheetah to add the .targets file to the project. No extra config required now. More info at https://github.com/sayedihashimi/slow-cheetah/issues/113.